Jedis Socket time out exception
I am getting this exception in jedis
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
do not know the exact reason. I am using jedis version 5.1.3.
Can some one help me with this ?
we were using jedis version 4.0.0 we were getting this exception now upgraded to 5.1.3 we are still getting the same exception
